# What is the significane of bean id activemqTx?

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-camel

I've been having trouble with Camel transactions and after some great help from the camel list I eventually tracked it down to using org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent in a bean with id 'activemq'. If I use an id of 'activemqTx' it works. But I can't seem to find any documentation on the significance of 'activemqTx' as a bean id.

only one message gets through the route with this:

```
<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
```

everything works with this:

```
<bean id="activemqTx" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
```

Comment: Seems to be a red herring. Calling the bean anything apart from 'activemq' works. Must be a bean clash somewhere...

Comment: that is strange...either way, mark as answered/closed...

Answer (score 0):

Must have been a bean name clash